# accessing array of objects after exporting in jsx

Tags: reactjs, jsx

i have contacts.js as below which has array(contacts) of 2 objects and i am exporting this array.

```
    const contacts = [
      {
        name: "xx",
        imgURL:"xx",
        phone: "xx",
        email: "xx"
      },{
        name: "xxx",
        imgURL:"xxx",
        phone: "xxx",
        email: "xxx"
      }
]

    export default contacts
```

in my jsx file below i am accessing this array by importing it. but when i try to print one specific object of array, the output is printed as undefined. also, i want to pass this objects as properties to my component. is there any way to achieve this?

my jsx file

```
import React from "react";
import ContactCard from "./ConactCard";
var contacts = require("/src/contacts.js");

function App() {
  return (
    <div>
      <ContactCard contacts={contacts[0]} />
      <ContactCard contacts={contacts[1]} />
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

my Contactcard.jsx is as below

```
function ContactCard(props){
  return (
    <div>
      <h1>{props.name}</h1>
      <img src={props.imgUrl}/>
      </div>
  )
}
export default ContactCard
```

Comment: have you tried with the correct prop names, e.g. `<ContactCard {...contacts[0]} />`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're accessing the property incorrectly.

Try this:

```
function ContactCard(props){
  return (
    <div>
      <h1>{props.contacts.name}</h1> // correct
      <img src={props.imgUrl}/> // incorrect
      </div>
  )
}
export default ContactCard
```

you can also destructure the props:

```
function ContactCard({ contacts }) {
  return (
    <div>
      <h1>{contacts.name}</h1> 
      <img src={contacts.imgUrl}/> 
      </div>
  )
}
export default ContactCard
```

or you can spread the contacts object in the parent:

```
function App() {
  return (
    <div>
      <ContactCard {...contacts[0]} />
      <ContactCard {...contacts[1]} />
    </div>
  );
}

function ContactCard(props){
  return (
    <div>
      <h1>{props.name}</h1>
      <img src={props.imgUrl}/>
      </div>
  )
}
```

Comment: when i try to print contacts[0] in the main jsx file i am getting undefined. also, inside the props as well.

Comment: @anonymous_coder - Try importing in this way: `import contacts from '/src/contacts.js';` also make sure that you're using the correct path.

Answer (score 1):

You are accessing the props in `ContactCard` incorrectly. You can choose to destructure the props in `ContactCard` like this.

```
function ContactCard({ contacts: { name, imgUrl } }){
  return (
    <div>
      <h1>{name}</h1>
      <img src={imgUrl}/>
    </div>
  )
}
export default ContactCard
```

Comment: problem got solved by changing the require statement with import